# Runtime.getRuntime().exec adaptation for Linux

Tags: runtime.exec

I know similar questions have been asked already but I cannot adapt the previous answers to my specific situation, so I'd greatly appreciate any help.

I use the following code in Windows and it works perfectly fine.

```
try
{
Process protSpec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd", "/c", "obspectrophore -i Rv0001.fasta > Rv0001.spec" });
            protSpec.waitFor();
}
catch (Exception e1)
{
System.out.println(e1.toString());
e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Trying to adapt it to Linux, I cut the "cmd", "/c" of the above code to get

```
    try
    {
    Process protSpec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"obspectrophore -i Rv0001.fasta > Rv0001.spec" });
                protSpec.waitFor();
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
    System.out.println(e1.toString());
    e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now I am getting the error message

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "obspectrophore -i Rv0001.fasta > Rv0001.spec": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

Any ideas for solving this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Linux equivalent of `cmd /c` is `sh -c`. The command syntax is the same in this case:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
    "sh", "-c", "obspectrophore -i Rv0001.fasta > Rv0001.spec" 
});
```

Your attempted Linux command doesn't run the command through a command interpretter, which is why it fails (this is the equivalent of pasting Java code into a DOS prompt, hoping that DOS will figure it out and run it anyways).

Answer (score 0):

Set `obspectrophore` in environment so that it can be accessed from any directory, as well make sure user having executing permission.